# Sort the two-dimensional sheet containing the objects of the class by the given field

Tags: python, sorting

I can not sort a two-dimensional list that contains objects of the class by the given field. I have a list of ArrayCD, which contains objects class musicCD. I address them in the following way:

```
for i in range(len(sortArrayCD)):
    print(sortArrayCD[i].getSinger(), sortArrayCD[i].getEdition(), sortArrayCD[i].getRecordsCount())
```

How can I sort this list by a given field. For example, on getEdition().

```
ArrayCD = sorted(ArrayCD, key=itemgetter(1))    
ArrayCD = sorted(ArrayCD, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Such options do not help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, assuming the output of your `getEdition` method is of a consistent and sortable type.

```
ArrayCD = sorted(ArrayCD, key=lambda x: x.getEdition())
```

Comment: Thank you very much